# Invoking a Virtual Machine in VMware workstation using Packer in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, packer, vmware-workstation

My setup is pretty simple. Here it is, I have a shell script which checks some pre-requisites and then initiates Packer build where a custom shell script runs as provisioner. Recently, I moved it to a job in Jenkins. But it throws below error while Packer triggers the build:

```
 [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Building and writing VMX file [0m
 [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Starting HTTP server on port 8784 [0m
 [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Starting virtual machine... [0m
 [1;31m==> vmware-iso: Error starting VM: VMware error: Error: Cannot launch the UI because no display server is present in the current environment [0m
 [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Waiting 4.765878987s to give VMware time to clean up... [0m
 [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Deleting output directory... [0m
 [1;31mBuild 'vmware-iso' errored: Error starting VM: VMware error: Error: Cannot launch the UI because no display server is present in the current environment [0m

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vmware-iso: Error starting VM: VMware error: Error: Cannot launch the UI because no display server is present in the current environment

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

It is unable to start the VM using VMware workstation. 
What has been done so far :

1. An extensive googling gave me an idea that Jenkins should have
   permission to start UI application.
2. As a workaround I tried starting VMware workstation before triggering the job but no luck. This trick worked with VirtualBox
   but not with VMware workstation.
3. Searched for vmware related plugins with Jenkins but couldn't find any.

Please can anyone point out if I'm doing something wrong or at least a way to get out of this ?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that you have `"headless": true`. If that is not enough you should run with [X virtual framebuffer](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml).

Answer (score 1):

The UI issue can be solved by setting correct value for DISPLAY parameter.
Add this command before invoking the script

> export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

Comment: This starts the VM but in background. I don't have access to the VM console and can't see the bootstrapping. I might end up in trouble if there's no progress in the console and in the end it times out.